# How to clear a text field using Robot Framework?

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, sikuli

I'm using the Sikuli Library with Robot Framework to run tests for a local windows application. Most solutions online are selenium based but I believe that only to work for web applications.

Entering text has been fine for the empty fields when there isn't a default value concerned.

Currently, I'm dealing with a field that contains a default value of 5000 but I need to change it to 10.

Text Field:

[image: Text Field]

So far I've tried things such as:

- Double-clicking the field first to highlight then type over (Input Text single clicks and removes highlight anyway)
- Single-Clicking as Input text single clicks itself (Does not happen fast enough to simulate a double click)

Comment: Send 4 BACKSPACE characters before sending the new number using `Input text`.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I'm not so sure how to do that do I have to use ASCII codes?

Comment: You can try `\b` or ASCII or you can check if Sikuli Library says anything about it. For example with SeleniumLibrary `BACKSPACE` is a special input which will send a backspace. I am not familiar with  Sikuli Library, you have to experiment a bit to see what are the possibilities. This was just an idea hence comment not answer. :)

Comment: Any luck with the backspace?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer in Sikuli terms. You just execute Ctrl+a to select content of the cell and then type 10

```
type('a', KeyModifier.CTRL)
type('10)
```